# Notepad++ inserts a blank line between each line of code when uploading file with filezilla

Tags: notepad++, filezilla

I want to download  php files from my sever with Filezilla, in order to back them up and to back them up on my computer. So before making any change of code I'd be certain to have the lastest version that used to work. When tired at night, it is too easy to overwrite an existing file.

But when I download files, they open up in Notepad++ with **a blank line** between each line of code. It is not readable anymore and it makes a 800 lines page a 1600 one ! Removing each blank line one by one turns you mad.

Is there a quick way to remove blank lines afterwards or a way to keep this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: Try regular expressions.

Comment: Try converting them into .txt. I've never had this problem with Filezilla.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem. Change transfer file type setting of filezilla to binary and it won't give blank lines anymore.

Here is how to do it:

Go to `Edit` > `Settings` > `Transfers` > `File Types`

There you can select `Binary` transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have this problem because you are reading the file as a UNIX file while it was created by a windows system.

If your server is a UNIX system you should use a replace. Put `\r` as search, leave the replace empty and select the extended research.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I found out the simplest way to do it.

**Just do NOT right click EDIT on your remote file**

( if your files are set to open automaticaly with Notepad++, a blank line will be inserted after every single line of code )

**Instead :**

- Create a copy folder of your pubic_html on your HD
- Transfer a copy of all your files to this folder with Filezilla.
- ->>>The back up will be done in seconds and all php files will open normaly in Notepad++